# rosserial_xbee in ros groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there still a package for rosserial xbee in ros groovy??
Kindly help me out.. I am not able to figure it out..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66740/rosserial_xbee-in-ros-groovy/) by [saurabh_shandilya](https://answers.ros.org/users/5342/saurabh_shandilya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial_xbee was just added. Install from https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial here using the directions

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saurabh_shandilya](https://answers.ros.org/users/5342/saurabh_shandilya/) on 2013-07-09**:
thanks a lot, balto!!